# Failed to query from fabcar

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric

I want to insert new car or query using a web application. Within this app.js, I use POST and GET method to insert new car or view all.

[image]

But every time, when I try to submit a new car or click "View All cars", it returns this error

[image]

[SOLVED]

await gateway.disconnect();

This is the villain, HA!! It disconnects the gateway and errupts the connection between chaincode. Thus, I am getting this "can not read from peer" error. I just omit this line and now it is working fine.